# How to properly use movement components in unreal engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm trying to set up a very simple RTS-like camera that moves around at the pressure of wasd or the arrow keys. But I can't manage to make it work.

I have a player controller that handles input like so:

```
void AMyPlayerController::SetupInputComponent()
{
    Super::SetupInputComponent();

    InputComponent->BindAxis("CameraForward", this, &AMyPlayerController::CameraForward);
}

void AMyPlayerController::CameraForward(float Amount)
{
    MyRtsCameraReference->CameraForward(Amount);
}
```

In my camera actor, which inherits from APawn, and I initialize like this:

```
ARtsCamera::ARtsCamera()
{
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    CameraComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("CameraComponent"));
    SpringArm = CreateDefaultSubobject<USpringArmComponent>(TEXT("SpringArm"));

    // I tried to use a static mesh in place of this but nothing changes.
    SceneRoot = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("SceneRoot"));

    MovementComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UFloatingPawnMovement>(TEXT("MovementComponent"));

    SpringArm->TargetArmLength = 500.f;

    SetRootComponent(SceneRoot);
    SpringArm->SetupAttachment(SceneRoot);
    CameraComponent->SetupAttachment(SpringArm);

    SpringArm->AddLocalRotation(FRotator(0.f, -50.f, 0.f));
}
```

I try to handle the movement like this:

```
void ARtsCamera::CameraForward(float Amount)
{
    if (Amount != 0)
    {
        // Here speed is a float used to control the actual speed of this movement.
        // If Amount is printed here, I get the correct value of 1/-1 at the pressure of w/s.
        MovementComponent->AddInputVector(GetActorForwardVector() * Amount * Speed);
    }
}
```

In my set up i then create a blueprint which inherits from this to expose to the level design phase a few parameters like Speed or the spring arm length and so on, but this shouldn't be the issue as if I use the C++ class the behaviour is the same.

The following works as expected (except for the fact that when i then rotate the camera, vectors get messed up) but i would like to use a movement component.

```
void ARtsCamera::CameraForward(float Amount)
{
    if (Amount != 0)
    {
        AddActorWorldOffset(GetActorForwardVector() * Amount * CameraMovingSpeed);
    }
}
```

The mobility is set to movable. And so far everything seems to be simple enough, no compile errors, but the actor doesn't move. What am I missing?

Also would you use the FloatingPawnMovement for this or would you go for another movement component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that your movement component is named 'UFloatingPawnMovement' makes me think it's probably meant to be a component on a APawn class, not AActor. UE4 is open source and you can look into the source code of UFloatingPawnMovement to verify this. You can also look in APawn and ACharacter to see how the movement components are used there.

Comment: You're right, I wrote AActor but I was actually inheriting from APawn. Edited that. Also I looked at the DefaultPawn code and it seems really similar to what I'm doing so i can't find what I'm doing wrong. I'll do some more tests tho. Thanks